# Quick and dirty way to access files external to Django?

Tags: python, django, permissions

I'm working on a demo for a program that creates some files on its own directory. This demo will be shown to someone physically far, via VPN, so I made a simple django project just to receive an input, call some scripts and display the output - the generated file. However, I don't have permission to open the file to display it since it's on a directory outside of the django project (the result is a permission denied error).

I'm aware it's not good practice or even safe for a web server to have access to files outside of its directories, but since this will run in a closed environment for a short amount of time only, is there a workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of it this way - If web server can generate the files , it can display them also.

As for your answer - if you know the path of the file, use the python open built in method to open the file and render the result to a template.

```
data = open('file_path').read().decode('utf-8')
render(request, template, context={data:data})
```

Comment: I should have been more specific, I'm sorry. It's a .wav file that I'm trying to embed with an `audio` tag. From what I understand of the tag, I have to pass the location of the file to the `src`...

Comment: No, now you are asking about serving the file. If you want django to serve it, it should be accessible in the static dir. So either add the path of the file location to staticfiles-dirs in settings - like here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#staticfiles-dirs or change the generated path of the file to the static dir in your app. Basically after that you can serve the static file.